# join with a lateral view is not supported

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am running below query and getting error **join with a lateral view is not supported**

```
select e.fileVersion, e.fileID, e.filedate
 from table_1
 lateral view explode(filedata) fileTable as e join table2 r
 where
     e.fileVersion = r.fileVersion
```

Here I want to join 2 tables with  fileVersion,
Can anyone tell how to fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

```
select  t.*

from           (select  ft.f.fileVersion
                       ,ft.f.fileID
                       ,ft.f.filedate

                from    table_1 t
                        lateral view explode(t.filedata) ft as f
                ) t

        join    table2 r

        on      t.fileVersion = r.fileVersion
```

Comment: This could be performance hit right ? , query for  table_1 fetches all the records and then comparing data with table2, - sorry if I am wrong, I am new to sql and hive

Comment: You think that putting something in a sub-query makes a difference for the optimizer?

Comment: Does it? @David דודו Markovitz
Wouldn't Hive create a temp file and move from there for the other join?